# First ID won't be excluded in wp_dropdown_pages with an $arg from tax_query

Tags: dropdown, php, tax-query

I'm having trouble to exclude specific posts in wp_dropdown_pages. Exclude seems to work, but the first ID of my foreach is ever and ever include in the dropdown... I don't understand why...

My get_posts query

```
$exclude_posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'organic-pickup',
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 72 //TODO Get all ID of taxonomy 'type' terms where types_metabox_dropdown = types_metabox_dropdown_no
                )
        )
        ));
```

My foreach with output formated to match wp_dropdown_pages parameters.

```
foreach($exclude_posts as $exclude_post) {
            $excludes[] = $exclude_post->ID;
        }
        $exclude = implode(',',$excludes);
        $excluded = "'" . $exclude . "'";
        print_r($excluded);
```

My dropdown

```
$ogpk_pickup_field_args = array (
            'depth' => -1,
            'class' => 'store-pickup form-row-wide',
            'show_option_none' => __( 'Choisissez le point relais où retirer votre panier', 'organic-pickup' ),
            'name' => 'store_pickup',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            // 'exclude' => '1074,1072,1059',
            'exclude' => $excluded, //TODO get excluded working please...
            'post_type' => 'organic-pickup',
            'value_field' => 'ID',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );
        wp_dropdown_pages( $ogpk_pickup_field_args );
```

I commentend out an exclude line with '1047,1072,1059'. With this param, the dropdown works fine and don't dispaly this posts.
The print_r($excluded) display this exact string... but put in the dropdown param, it always display the post corresponding to the first ID...
I'm completly unable to understand why... Any hint folks?

Comment: don't add the single quotes. literals are enclosed in quotes to show it's a string, $exclude is already a string variable. Just pass $exclude, don't need $excluded at all.

Comment: You are right inarilo! I've had so much trouble before finding implode to add comma to my output that I didn't test $exclude alone... You saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add single quotes before using $exclude. Literals are enclosed in quotes to show it's a string, but since $exclude is already a string variable, you can pass it directly.

Remove $excluded, you don't need it at all and just use

```
$ogpk_pickup_field_args = array (
        'depth' => -1,
        'class' => 'store-pickup form-row-wide',
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Choisissez le point relais où retirer votre panier', 'organic-pickup' ),
        'name' => 'store_pickup',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        // 'exclude' => '1074,1072,1059',
        'exclude' => $exclude,
        'post_type' => 'organic-pickup',
        'value_field' => 'ID',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
```